# Eliminar signos diacríticos en JavaScript. Eliminar tildes (acentos ortográficos), virgulillas, diéresis, cedillas

Tags: javascript, regex, utf-8, unicode, ecmascript-6

**Contexto.** Intento eliminar las tildes (acentos ortográficos) y virgulillas, para comparar 2 palabras. Hice la función:

```js
let sinDiacriticos = (function(){
    let de = 'ÁÃÀÄÂÉËÈÊÍÏÌÎÓÖÒÔÚÜÙÛÑÇáãàäâéëèêíïìîóöòôúüùûñç',
         a = 'AAAAAEEEEIIIIOOOOUUUUNCaaaaaeeeeiiiioooouuuunc',
        re = new RegExp('['+de+']' , 'ug');

    return texto =>
        texto.replace(
            re, 
            match => a.charAt(de.indexOf(match))
        );
})();


let prue = 'Épico año de mal agüero, sólo Óscar y Ángel ganarán ésta. -Ímpetú Úrsula. ¡Ñañdú corre rápido por ahí!';
console.log(sinDiacriticos(prue));
```

**Pregunta 1.** ¿Hay alguna forma directa de reemplazar **cualquier [signo diacrítico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signo_diacr%C3%ADtico)** sin la necesidad de generar manualmente un mapa de reemplazos?
Me interesan cubrir las marcas diacríticas de cualquier lenguaje.

**Pregunta 2.** Teniendo en cuenta que en español la `ñ` es una letra diferente de la `n`, ¿se pueden eliminar los diacríticos excepto si es una `ñ`?
<sub><sup>* Pregunta hecha por [blonfu](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/7176/blonfu) en [comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/62031/eliminar-signos-diacr%C3%ADticos-en-javascript-eliminar-tildes-acentos-ortogr%C3%A1ficos/62032?noredirect=1#comment241819_62032)</sup></sub>

Comment: Publiqué porque 1- fueron varias veces que comentamos / hablamos de esto, y 2 - para que agreguen respuestas alternativas que puedan aportar otros métodos

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Desde ECMAScript 6 (2015), se puede utilizar [**String.prototype.normalize()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) para llevar a la forma descompuesta de [normalización](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-css-normalization.es) en Unicode (ver [compatibilidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize#Browser_compatibility)).

Esto significa que un caracter (*en realidad un "punto de código"*) puede ser descompuesto en su equivalencia de caracter base, seguido de sus marcas. Por ejemplo:

[image: Source -> NFD NFC]

Ambas formas son equivalentes y se imprimen igual.

En la forma [**NFD**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normal_forms), los diacríticos son *code points* (~caracteres) diferentes.
Y lo importante es que **todas las marcas diacríticas están en el rango `U+0300` - `U+036F`**.

---

### Código (para todos los lenguajes)

Lleva a la forma descompuesta, y elimina el bloque [*Combining Diacritial Marks*](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/combining_diacritical_marks/list.htm).

```js
// Elimina los diacríticos de un texto (ES6)
//
function eliminarDiacriticos(texto) {
    return texto.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g,"");
}
```

Pruebas:

```js
// Elimina los diacríticos de un texto (ES6)
//
function eliminarDiacriticos(texto) {
    return texto.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g,"");
}


//  Prueba

function mostrarSinDiacriticos(inp){
    document.getElementById('muestra')
        .innerText = eliminarDiacriticos(inp.value);
}

mostrarSinDiacriticos(texto);
```

```html
Texto:
<input id="texto" oninput="mostrarSinDiacriticos(this)" style="width:100%" value="áéíóúñüÁÉÍÓÚÑÜ">
Sin Diacríticos:
<div id="muestra" />
```

---

### Diacríticos excepto en la `ñ` (sólo español)

1. Podemos sacar sólo los acentos en vocales o la diéresis en la `ü`.
   Descomponemos, eliminamos los diacríticos exclusivamente de `áéíóúü` y volvemos a componer:

   ```
   texto.normalize('NFD')
        .replace(/([aeio])\u0301|(u)[\u0301\u0308]/gi,"$1$2")
        .normalize();
   ```

2. O podemos eliminar cualquier diacrítico (para cualquier lenguaje) excepto si es una `ñ`:

   ```
   // Elimina los diacríticos de un texto excepto si es una "ñ" (ES6)
   //
   function eliminarDiacriticosEs(texto) {
       return texto
              .normalize('NFD')
              .replace(/([^n\u0300-\u036f]|n(?!\u0303(?![\u0300-\u036f])))[\u0300-\u036f]+/gi,"$1")
              .normalize();
   }
   ```

   Pruebas:

   ```js
   // Elimina los diacríticos de un texto excepto si es una "ñ" (ES6)
   //
   function eliminarDiacriticosEs(texto) {
       return texto
              .normalize('NFD')
              .replace(/([^n\u0300-\u036f]|n(?!\u0303(?![\u0300-\u036f])))[\u0300-\u036f]+/gi,"$1")
              .normalize();
   }


   //  Prueba

   function mostrarSinDiacriticos(inp){
       document.getElementById('muestra')
           .innerText = eliminarDiacriticosEs(inp.value);
   }

   mostrarSinDiacriticos(texto);
   ```

   ```html
   Texto:
   <input id="texto" oninput="mostrarSinDiacriticos(this)" style="width:100%" value="áéíóúñüÁÉÍÓÚÑÜ">
   Sin Diacríticos:
   <div id="muestra" />
   ```

Comment: Una duda, ¿cómo mantenemos la *ñ*? La virgulilla de la *ñ* no es algo añadido a una letra sino que forma parte de la letra y no queremos cambiar la *ñ* por una *n*: No es lo mismo *año* que *ano*, *moño* que *mono*, *uña* que *una*, etc.

Comment: Muy buena idea @blonfu. Edité pregunta y respuesta, dejando ambas opciones. Estoy seguro que hay casos de uso para las 2 alternativas (con o sin `ñ`).