# Palindromo en frases

Tags: javascript

Buenas, tengo un pequeño ejercicio realizado en javascript en el cual determina si una palabra introducida por teclado es palidromo o no. Con palabras si me funciona correctamente pero al introducir una frase me salta siempre con que no es palindromo.

Código:

```js
function palindromo() {
  var texto;
  var alReves;

  texto = prompt("Introduce texto o palabra: ");
  alReves = cambiar(texto);

  if (texto == alReves) {
    document.write("Palindromo");
  } else {
    document.write("No palindromo");
  }
}

function cambiar(texto) {
  return texto.split("").reverse().join("");
}

palindromo();
```

Comment: Acabo de probar tu código y funciona bien. Ej: "soy y yos" responde `Palindromo`; "soy yo" responde `No palindromo`.

Comment: Cierto a mi tambien me funciona, pero con otras frases no funciona no se porque

Comment: Tendrías que quitar espacios, poner todo en minuscula como te dice @IñigoIrigoyenErquicia y los acentos. No sé si me olvido de alguna otra cosa

Comment: Puedes poner los casos concretos que no te funcionan?

Comment: Como podría hacer sin que cuente los espacios en blancos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenas, según las anotaciones de **@blonfu** te muestro un ejemplo donde:

1. Se eliminan los espacios
2. Se pasa todo a minúscula
3. Se quitan los acentos (del castellano).

```js
function palindromo() {
  var texto;
  var alReves;

  texto = getCadenaSinAcentos(prompt("Introduce texto o palabra: ").replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase());
  alReves = cambiar(texto);

  if (texto == alReves) {
    document.write("Palindromo");
  } else {
    document.write("No palindromo");
  }
}

function cambiar(texto) {
  return texto.split("").reverse().join("");
}

function getCadenaSinAcentos(cadena) {
  // Quitamos acentos.
  cadena = cadena.replace(/á/gi, "a");
  cadena = cadena.replace(/é/gi, "e");
  cadena = cadena.replace(/í/gi, "i");
  cadena = cadena.replace(/ó/gi, "o");
  cadena = cadena.replace(/ú/gi, "u");
  return cadena;
}


palindromo();
```

Comment: Para complementar, pueden leer [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/62032/16597) sobre como eliminar acentos y signos diacríticos

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser problema de mayúsculas ya que "Apa" no es igual a "apA". Prueba a hacer esto, sino intentaré ofrecerte otra cosa.

```
function palindromo()
{
    var texto;
    var alReves;

    texto = prompt("Introduce texto o palabra: ");
    alReves = cambiar(texto);

    if(texto.toLowerCase() == alReves.toLowerCase())
    {
        document.write("Palindromo");
    }
    else
    {
        document.write("No palindromo");
    }
}

function cambiar(texto)
{
    return texto.split("").reverse().join("");
}
```

Comment: Acabo de probarlo amigo y  no me funciona

Comment: añade esto texto.trim() y alReves.trim() antes de compararlos

Comment: Sino   texto.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'');    y    alReves.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'');