# ¿Comó hacer que el prompt me pegunte lo que quiero y lo verifique?

Tags: javascript, funciones

Mi pregunta es, tienen alguna idea de como puedo hacer que cuando escriba una palabra dentro del `prompt` me salga un `alert` diciendo si la palabra es o no palíndromo

```js
function Palindroma(cadena) {
  t = cadena.length
  if (t === 0) {
    /*Si ni hay caracteres no puede ser palindroma*/
    return false;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < t / 2; i++) {
    if (cadena[i] === cadena[t - i - 1]) {
      return alert(` es palindromo`);
    }
    return alert(`No es palindromo`);
  }
}
Palindroma = prompt(`l`)
```

Y que se adapte al código

Comment: Hola, ¿necesitas ayuda con la lógica o con asignar el valor del `promt()` a la función o con ambos?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Palindromo en frases](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/129580/palindromo-en-frases)

Answer (score 3):

En lugar de iterar, se puede resolver asi:

- Se convierte el string en array usando destructuring [...].
- lo damos vuelta con `reverse()`.
- Hacemos un `join()` para que vuelva a ser string (ya esta dado vuelta).
- Comparamos ambos strings.

```js
const str = prompt(`escribe una palabra`);

if([...str].reverse().join("") === str){
    alert("es palindromo");
}else{
    alert("no es palindromo");
}
```

La iteración en realidad es una solución óptima (pero mas larga), porque un palíndromo es tal si cada letra cumple la condición, de manera que lo que podemos hacer es buscar justamente **el caso en el que no se cumpla la condición** (`!==`), y en dicho caso podemos dejar de iterar.

Además, tal como en el intento que hiciste, podemos iterar solo la mitad del string. Entonces, teniendo en cuenta lo dicho, estos son los cambios que haría a tu función para que funcione:

```js
function Palindroma(cadena) {
  t = cadena.length
  if (t === 0) {return false;}

  for (i = 0; i < t / 2; i++) {
  
    //!!verificamos solo si no cumple la condición
    if (cadena[i] !== cadena[t - i - 1]) {
      return alert(`No es palindromo`);
    }

  }
  //retornamos fuera del for, porque si paso el for
  //es que es un palíndromo
  return alert(`Es palindromo`);
}

//Pasamos el prompt como argumento
Palindroma(prompt(`ingrese un string`));
```

Comment: un ejemplo para probar la función: `anitalagordalagartonanotragaladrogalatina`

Comment: @Marcos gracias por la acotación, muchas veces dejo ese tema a otros, porque usualmente llego tarde a responder, pero es verdad que es algo muy importante el hecho de explicar que es lo que falla y porque.