# Comparando caracteres javascript

Tags: javascript

alguien me puede decir que esta mal?
es un metodo palindromo que deberia retorna true en caso que la palabra se lea igual tanto de adelante para atras como de atras para delante y deberia devolver false si no lo fuera
gracias

```
***const palindromo = palabra =>{
  palabra = palabra.toLowerCase();
  let x="";
  let y="";
  
for(let i=1; i<= palabra.length; i++){
  x = palabra[i-1]
  y = palabra[palabra.length-i]
    }
  if(x === y){
    return true
  }else if (x !==y){
    return false
}

}

console.log(palindromo("enrique"));***
```

Comment: Esta pregunta ya tiene una respuesta aquí: [Palindromo en frases](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/129580/palindromo-en-frases)

Answer (score 1):

Debes comparar x e y dentro del bucle for, si no sólo comparas la última iteración.

Qué por cierto, es lo mismo que le pasa a Cris223511.dev. Sólo que en su caso funciona porque en el ejemplo concreto de "luzazul" en la última iteración compara las "z", pero si pruebas con "puzazul" verás que también te resuelve a true.

Lo que yo haría es comparar x e y dentro del for, con una variable booleana que se pondrá a false en el momento en que x e y sean diferentes (se podría mejorar el algoritmo saliendo del bucle en ese momento, ya que no es necesario seguir comparando) y como bien dice Cris223511.dev es suficiente con comparar como mucho hasta length/2.

Quedaría algo así:

```
const palindromo = palabra =>{
  palabra = palabra.toLowerCase();
  let x="";
  let y="";
  let pal=true;
  
  for(let i=1; i<= palabra.length / 2; i++){
    x = palabra[i-1]
    y = palabra[palabra.length-i]
    if(x !== y) {
      pal=false;
    }
  }
  return pal;
}    
    
console.log(palindromo("salas"));
console.log(palindromo("enrique"));
```

Comment: Si `pal` es falso al menos una vez, eso debería terminar la ejecución, no? Para qué seguir si el par no coincide?

Comment: Sí, de hecho en mi propio post lo comento: "se podría mejorar el algoritmo saliendo del bucle en ese momento, ya que no es necesario seguir comparando". Mi código es un borrador rápido para que pudiera ver donde fallaba el suyo, pero tampoco es la solución óptima. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Faltaba un pequeño detalle, la longitud se tiene que dividir en 2 para dividir el número de iteraciones dentro del bucle. También, se añadió las funciones `split()` y `join()`. El método `split()` se utiliza para dividir la cadena en un array con el carácter de espacio en blanco `" "` como delimitador, y luego vendría el uso del método `join()` para convertir el array en una cadena nuevamente.

```js
const palindromo = palabra => {
palabra = palabra.toLowerCase().split(" ").join("");
let x = "";
let y = "";

for (let i = 1; i <= palabra.length / 2; i++) {
    x = palabra[i - 1]
    y = palabra[palabra.length - i]
}
if (x === y) {
    return true
} else if (x !== y) {
    return false
}

}

console.log(palindromo("enrique"));
console.log(palindromo("luz azul"));
```

Serían necesarios utilizar estos métodos para que la verificación de que si es o no es palíndromo sea tanto para 1 a más palabras.

Comment: En lugar de `.split(" ").join("")`, no crees que sea más apropiado `.replace(" ", "")`? No solo esto... como la comparación está fuera del for, sólo va a comparar el primer y último caracter. A esta respuesta le falta.

Comment: Gracias por la observación, la condición debería estar dentro del for. Respecto a lo del `.replace(" ", "")` los resultados vendrían a ser los mismos., cualquiera de las 2 opciones serían válidas.

Comment: Sí y no. El resultado sí es el mismo, pero en términos de semántica, e incluso, desempeño, son diferente. En uno de ellos estás creando un arreglo de `string` de `n` elementos (podrían ser decenas, o cientos, dependiendo del largo de la frase) y luego los estás uniendo con un `.join`, realizando dos operaciones; y en el otro, estás únicamente  devolviendo **una** instancia de `string` nueva, con el caracter cambiado. Así que, no... no son lo mismo