# ¿cual es el regexp que usa datatables para filtrar informacion?

Tags: javascript, regex, datatables

estoy usando datatables y un filtro personalizado, necesita filtrar informacion de un campo usando la misma funcion de filtrado de datatable pero en un solo campo, es decir necesito saber cual es la expresion regular que usa datatables para buscar cualquier palabra clave que coincida con la que se esta buscando.

le agradesco la ayuda.

Comment: Probablemente no necesites una expresión regular, [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/indexOf) podría ser suficiente. Para considerar caracteres con tilde, tal vez necesites [normalizar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/62031/eliminar-signos-diacr%C3%ADticos-en-javascript-eliminar-tildes-acentos-ortogr%C3%A1ficos#answer-62032) tanto el dato de entrada como el de búsqueda.

Comment: sí ya estoy usando indexOf, funciona como lo necesitaba.