# metodo .replace para quitar acentos

Tags: javascript

Me encuentro desarrollando un encriptador de texto con HTML5, actualmente estoy construyendo la función para reemplazar acentos. este es mi código en JS:

```
var textoPrueba = "esté es ún textó de pruebá í";
var removetxt;

//Función para reemplazar acentos

function removeAccents (frase) {

    remove = frase.replace(/[á é í ó ú]/g,"a e i o u");
    return remove;
}

removetxt = removeAccents(textoPrueba);

console.log(removetxt);
```

Utilice el método **replace** con una expresión regular y el modificador **g**. La función reemplaza el carácter antiguo por toda la cadena nueva he imprime esto:

[image: resultado de la consola]

El resultado que busco es que reemplace solamente el carácter y pase al siguiente a carácter a reemplazar. ¿Cómo puedo lograr esto?.

Comment: El código va como texto. Para ti, que eres el interesado en recibir la ayuda, es solo copiar y pegar. Para los que pueden querer ayudarte, deben ir mirando la imagen y transcribir el código.

Comment: ya lo cambio, gracias

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Eliminar signos diacríticos en JavaScript. Eliminar tildes (acentos ortográficos), virgulillas, diéresis, cedillas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/62031/eliminar-signos-diacr%c3%adticos-en-javascript-eliminar-tildes-acentos-ortogr%c3%a1ficos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear un diccionario de transformaciones de esta manera:

```js
const textoPrueba = "esté es ún textó de pruebá í";

let diccionario =
{
  "á" : "a",
  "é" : "e",
  "í" : "i",
  "ó" : "o",
  "ú" : "u"
};

function removeAccents (frase) {

    remove = frase.replace(/á|é|í|ó|ú/g,function(a){
      return diccionario[a];
    });
    return remove;
}

let removetxt = removeAccents(textoPrueba);

console.log(removetxt);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, con esta respuesta encontre la solucion al problema anterior y modificandola me permite realizar la encriptacion de una cadena.

Comment: Qué bueno te haya servido!!!  La verdad que intuí que dado lo que estas realizando, podía servirte para más allá de este caso particular. Saludos y suerte en tu proyecto

Answer (score 2):

Puedes probar con esto [Aquí está la respuesta original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/remove-accents-diacritics-in-a-string-in-javascript)

```js
const str = "esté es ún textó de pruebá í";
let resp = str.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")

console.log(resp);
```

Comment: Hay Bastantes terminos que aun desconozco. Voy a comenzar a estudiarlos, muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Deberías explicar un poco tu respuesta. Sino es una publicación que solo muestra un enlace.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y responde cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Los enlaces pueden caer... Lee [answer].

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar .normalize() definiendo un REGEX:

```js
function quitarAcentos(str) {
    return str.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
}

console.log('Este es mi texto con caracteres acentuados: äáâ ëé íi őo üú ńn');
console.log(quitarAcentos('Este es mi texto resultante: äáâ ëé íi őo üú ńn'));
```

o usando .replace() detectando cada coincidencia del caracter acentuado o con diacriticos:

```js
quitarAcentos = (function() {
    var translate_re = /[¹²³áàâãäåaaaÀÁÂÃÄÅAAAÆccç©CCÇÐÐèéê?ëeeeeeÈÊË?EEEEE€gGiìíîïìiiiÌÍÎÏ?ÌIIIlLnnńñNNÑòóôõöooőoøÒÓÔÕÖOOOØŒr®Ršs?ßŠS?ùúûüuuuuÙÚÛÜUUUUýÿÝŸžzzŽZZ]/g;
    var translate = {
"¹":"1","²":"2","³":"3","á":"a","à":"a","â":"a","ã":"a","ä":"a","å":"a","a":"a","a":"a","a":"a","À":"a","Á":"a","Â":"a","Ã":"a","Ä":"a","Å":"a","A":"a","A":"a",
"A":"a","Æ":"a","c":"c","c":"c","ç":"c","©":"c","C":"c","C":"c","Ç":"c","Ð":"d","Ð":"d","è":"e","é":"e","ê":"e","?":"e","ë":"e","e":"e","e":"e","e":"e","e":"e",
"e":"e","È":"e","Ê":"e","Ë":"e","?":"e","E":"e","E":"e","E":"e","E":"e","E":"e","€":"e","g":"g","G":"g","i":"i","ì":"i","í":"i","î":"i","ï":"i","ì":"i","i":"i",
"i":"i","i":"i","Ì":"i","Í":"i","Î":"i","Ï":"i","?":"i","Ì":"i","I":"i","I":"i","I":"i","l":"l","L":"l","n":"n","n":"n","ñ":"n","N":"n","N":"n","Ñ":"n","ń":"n","ò":"o",
"ó":"o","ô":"o","õ":"o","ö":"o","o":"o","o":"o","o":"o","ø":"o","Ò":"o","ő":"o","Ó":"o","Ô":"o","Õ":"o","Ö":"o","O":"o","O":"o","O":"o","Ø":"o","Œ":"o","r":"r","®":"r",
"R":"r","š":"s","s":"s","?":"s","ß":"s","Š":"s","S":"s","?":"s","ù":"u","ú":"u","û":"u","ü":"u","u":"u","u":"u","u":"u","u":"u","Ù":"u","Ú":"u","Û":"u","Ü":"u",
"U":"u","U":"u","U":"u","U":"u","ý":"y","ÿ":"y","Ý":"y","Ÿ":"y","ž":"z","z":"z","z":"z","Ž":"z","Z":"z","Z":"z"
    };
    return function(s) {
        return(s.replace(translate_re, function(match){return translate[match];}) );
    }
})();

   console.log('Este es mi texto con caracteres acentuados: äáâ ëé íi őo üú ńn');
    console.log(quitarAcentos('Este es mi texto resultante: äáâ ëé íi őo üú ńn'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo reemplazando vocal por vocal, así:

```js
var textoPrueba = "esté es ún textó de pruebá í";
var removetxt;

function removeAccents(frase) {
  remove = frase.replace(/[á]/g, "a").replace(/[é]/g, "e").replace(/[í]/g, "i").replace(/[ó]/g, "o").replace(/[ú]/g, "u");
  return remove;
}

removetxt = removeAccents(textoPrueba);
console.log(removetxt);
```

Comment: Me funciono tu respuesta y entendi como lo realizo, muchas gracias

Comment: @Reaper Me alegro, es una solución más sencilla para poder resolver tu problema, recuerda verificar la respuesta si te sirvió, saludos.